# What is the fastest way to obtain an index from a pointer of an array element in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, pointers

Suppose you have a pointer to an int from an array. Is this the best way to find out which item of the array the pointer points to?

```
int nmbr = pointer - &array[0];
cout<<"Item number "<<nmbr+1;
```

If the pointer pointed to the 6th item, would this always print "Item number 6"? Is this error-prone? Is there a faster way to do it? Iterating over the array won't work because of possible duplicate values, but does this always work? In this situation we assume the array starts from item 0 to item x. Is there a situation in which an array's items aren't stored in a continuous line (if the array was initialized as `int array[x];`)?

Comment: More generic:  `cout << std::distance(array, pointer) + 1;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `std::begin(array)`, if you want it to be generic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by XTF, yes it is guaranteed to work. There is however, no need for taking the address of the 0'th element, just use `array` as it is.

For a more generic solution, that will also work on other containers you could consider the following examples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    {
        int array[10];
        int * p = &array[5]; // Somehow get a pointer to the sixth element
        std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(array), p) << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::array<int, 10> array;
        int * p = &array[5]; // Somehow get a pointer to the sixth element
        std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(array), p) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `pointer` is known to point at an element of `array`, the

```
  std::ptrdiff_t nmbr = pointer - array;
```

will do it.  If pointer does not point at an element of the array, the behaviour is undefined.   `std::ptrdiff_t` is declared in the standard header `<cstddef>`, and is an implementation-defined signed integral type.   Using `int` is not a good idea, particularly for large arrays, since `std::ptrdiff_t` may be able to represent a larger range of values than an `int`  (and, if the value is larger than an `int` can represent, converting the result to `int` also gives undefined behaviour).

The `+1`s in your code are incorrect, since array indexing in C++ is zero based.

All arrays, in the sense of something declared as

```
  some_type array[some_positive_value];
```

have contiguous elements.   Note that C++ does not support C's VLAs (variable length arrays) i.e.  `some_positive_value` must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Both +1's look wrong..
But yes, this is the fastest and simplest way. It's guaranteed to work.

Comment: The +1's are because I want it to output the item number starting from 1, not from 0, thanks for the answer. EDIT: Sorry, didn't notice I had TWO +1's! Thanks again!

Comment: @Frank Puffer:Accidentally.